# change `dest` option on the fly

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have some grunt tasks to compile files and would like to "recycle" them inside different tasks.

I am trying to modify the destination directory without success... My idea is something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('bower', ['compile:index', 'compile:core'], function(){
    this.options({dest: 'dist/*.js'});
});
```

The `compile:index` task runs good by itself (i.e. when called alone) and has `dest: 'index.js`, other tasks have other filenames. I would like to change these inside the `bower`task, adding a new directory but keeping the filename defined in the original task.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish but you can modify the `dest` of a task with `grunt.config('compile.index.dest', 'dist/*.js');` and then run the tasks afterward with `grunt.task.run(['compile:index', 'compile:core']);`

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung, please add that as a answer. Its not 100% what I was looking for since they run async, but it is very nice information and I am using it a lot.

Comment: Added an answer with a little more advance usage of a dynamic alias task. Hopefully that is closer to the answer you're looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dynamic alias task that configures and then runs tasks like such:

```
grunt.registerTask('bower', function(target) {
  target = target || 'index';
  if (target === 'core') {
    grunt.config('compile.core.dest', 'dist/core.js');
  } else {
    grunt.config('compile.index.dest', 'dist/index.js');
    // Will call itself after compile:index has ran to configure for compile:core
    grunt.task.run(['compile:index', 'bower:core', 'compile:core']);
  }
});
```

Then entering `grunt bower` or `grunt bower:index` will dynamically configure/run the `compile:index` task, then configure/run the `compile:core` task.